# Insert into not working but query does

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

my issue is that I have a insert into inside of a stored procedure, and sometimes it says "No data found" the problem is that I know that there's data that can be selected with that criteria.

Also, the weird part is that I'm sure that the data is there because I use dbms_output.put_line to print on console the query with the values of the variables used, so I know it's exactly the same query executed inside the stored procedure, and If I execute the printed query it does return data.

Any idea of what's happening?

Thank you.

Comment: No code, no sample data. At a guess I'd say it's some quantum effect.

Comment: I can't use code for security/confidentiality reasons, but my main question is not for this particular case but why does the printed query works but it doesn't do it inside of the stored procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to find what was happening, seems that oracle has an issue when working with dates, the query inside of the procedure was receiving some dates, and even when it was oracle itself  generating the dates, it had some interpretation issues, so I just used 
***TO_CHAR(b, 'YYYY/MM/DD')*** to query the dates at the beginning and problem solved